# Manipulatinng JQuery's Autocomplete List

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to call my own function on JQuery's Autocomplete list.

JQuery Code:

```
//JQuery UI AutoComplete
$( "#tut_search" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: "PHP_Code/MyAjax.php?page=tut_search_ac"
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a href='javascript:alert();'>" + item.name + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Function is not calling on the clicking of autocomplete list.

Please give me any solution to call function on JQuery Autocomplete List.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_renderItem` function should be part of the `autocomplete` options:

```
$( "#tut_search" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: "PHP_Code/MyAjax.php?page=tut_search_ac",
    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a href='javascript:alert();'>" + item.name + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    }
}).data("autocomplete");
```